# SpiderMonkey Link Error: FloatingPoint.h not found

Tags: c++, linker, spidermonkey

I'm very new to spiderMonkey and have followed this tutorial to get started (I'm using MAC OS X): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/How_to_embed_the_JavaScript_engine

Every time I try to do the linking command in Step 6:

```
cl helloworld.cpp -link dist/lib/mozjs185-1.0.lib
```

I get the following 2 problems:
1) mozjs185-1.0.lib is not present in any directory (I've downloaded both the spiderMonkey and Mozilla source code)
2) Once I edit the path to point to the .lib file I do have I get the following error: FloatingPoint.h not found. However, I can find FloatingPoint.h on the system just at a different directory.

Could anyone give me a clue as to in which directory these header files should be? Or how to get the required .lib file? I've followed instructions on the mozilla development site meticulously and still can't get a hang of this.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours battling with this, I've managed to link properly by adding the hello world.cpp file in the build-release folder (as described in the Build Documentation; for more info see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation).

From the terminal, I then cd into the build-release folder and type in the following command:

```
g++ -Idist/include -Ldist/bin -lmozjs185  helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
```

Unfortunately I am still getting this error:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/atomic:539:2: **error: atomic is not implemented**

I am pretty sure this has to do with the c++ compiler installed, and I still have to find a workaround, but at least it's properly linking now!

Comment: Did you try with `-std=c++11`? (`g++ -std=c++11 -Idist/include -Ldist/bin -lmozjs185  helloworld.cpp -o helloworld`)